# how to generate des (semi-) weak keys?

Tags: des

Recently, i am learning about des algorithm, i know there are weak and semi-weak keys in des. we can get the (semi-) weak keys at http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/des-weak.html.

But what confused me is that how people get the (semi-)key list, we have 2^64 possible keys, my pc is 2.5GHz Duo i5, it may take hundreds years to Brute force the (semi-)key list.

So, my question is how do i effectively generate all the (semi-)key in my pc in several hours or days. Plus, i need to implement it with C or other languages. 
Thanks.

Comment: "it may take hundreds of years to brute force" - so can you use some maths or understanding of the key scheduling instead? The definition on the page is fairly clear - they're the keys that "generate only two or four different sub-keys instead of 16 different ones"

Comment: i know, but i also have to test the key from 0x0000000000000000 to 0xffffffffffffffff, otherwise how do i know it generate only two or four different sub-keys. thanks.

Comment: My point was that you don't need to test every key if you can understand the key scheduling algorithm well enough. So for example if we know the weak keys generate all zeros and all ones for the internal keys can you see an input that would give you all zeros for K1? Then try and solve the shifts and C functions for the next round to either give you all ones? Then try and solve the next round to go back to all zeroes again? Of course the sixteen keys may not cycle between zeros and ones, it might be two zeros, two ones, so perhaps look at ways of making a round stable too.

Comment: i don't quit understand your answers. Do you mean given a key, then test whether it is a (semi-)weak key? but i have to generate all (semi-)weak key! can you give the C implements, thanks.

Comment: No, I mean start with the core of the key schedule function, solve how it can output weak or semi-weak keys and then work back from there to see what inputs - the original keys - you need. No, sorry, I don't have any more specifics or an implementation.

Comment: i got it, you mean instead of brute forcing, we backstep the (semi-)key according to the definition. but still, i don't know how to backstep.